# How to reference a SQL table if primary key has more than one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am learning **postgresql** and I have created 2 tables: `goals` and `results`. Each table has a primary key which is formed by 3 columns:

- id
- valid_date_from
- vald_until_from

I did this so that each row must be unique not only by its id but also depending on when the **goal** or **result** is still valid. Here is my sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE goals (
  goal_id INT,
  goal_title VARCHAR(80),
  goal_description VARCHAR(300),
  goal_valid_from_date TIMESTAMP,
  goal_valid_until_date TIMESTAMP,
  goal_deleted_flag BOOLEAN,
  PRIMARY KEY (goal_id, goal_valid_from_date, goal_valid_until_date)
);

CREATE TABLE results (
  result_id INT,
  goal_id INT,
  result_description VARCHAR(300),
  result_target FLOAT,
  result_timestamp DATE,
  result_valid_from_date TIMESTAMP,
  result_valid_until_date TIMESTAMP,
  result_deleted_flag BOOLEAN,
  PRIMARY KEY (result_id, result_valid_from_date, result_valid_until_date)
);
```

My goal now is to create a **foreign key** so that I am able to connect the 2 tables based on the `goal_id` column only and not the `valid_from/until_date` columns otherwise they would never match.

I tried to achieve this by using the following lines of code:

```
ALTER TABLE results
ADD FOREIGN KEY(goal_id)
REFERENCES goals(goal_id) on delete set null;
```

However I get an error:

> SQL Error [42830]: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given
> keys for referenced table "goal"

Would you be able to propose a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal?

Comment: This does not address your issue directly, but please see this:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html  and look at the section on EXCLUDE constraints.  I think you will need three tables, one for goals, one for goal validity periods, and one for results.  Or, if a `goal_id` is never reused for a different validity period, then make `goal_id` the PK for goals.

Comment: This is where it all goes wrong: `I did this so that each row must be unique not only by its id but also depending on when the goal or result is still valid.` Sounds like a logic sentence, but falls apart on inspection. Please explain what you want to achieve *exactly*. My guess: you want PK(id) and an exclusion constraint on time ranges like Mike already suggested (but still just two tables).

Comment: I doubt your decision to put the two timestamps into the primary key. Does `goal_id` not identify a row? Can there be two entries with the same `goal_id`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the idea is that a goal can be tracked in history. For example goal_id=1 has some information which is valid from date 2022-01-01 until 2022-01-03 and then after I made some change i can still find it from 2022-01-03 until today for example.

Comment: Then mshabou's answer is the right one for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is very clear in  [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-altertable.html)

```
FOREIGN KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn [, ... ] ) ]
```

you need to put the list of column_name

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution! Would you be able to add the lines of code to achieve this based on my example as well please? :)

Comment: You have to add all the columns that make up the primary key to the `results` table and include them in the foreign key definition as shown by the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> ... so that I am able to connect the 2 tables based on the goal_id column only ...

As the error message already suggests, you need to add a matching UNIQUE CONSTRAINT:

```
ALTER TABLE goals
ADD CONSTRAINT u_goals_goal_id
UNIQUE (goal_id)
```

However, this constraint is more restrictive than your actual primary key, which might not be what you want, if your current design is on purpose and not by accident (see the comments of @MikeOrganek and @ErwinBrandstetter).

If it is what you want then you should consider making this your primary key instead.

For your exclusion problem (no two goals may have overlapping time periods) take a look at [the example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT), it literally describes your case.